# Parallel computing in R on Windows using doSNOW: How to transfer results from clusters back to master

Tags: r, parallel-processing

When using clusters in R on Windows I been trying to find a simple way to transfer results from a cluster to the master. If the results is an array or a simple number the .combine option of  foreach / %dopar% statement takes care of this, but if the result is a complex object lets such a randomForest model, how to transfer the whole model from the slave cluster back to the master?

I try: assing with `env=.Global` but it does not work on my Windows 7.

At the end I work around by saving the object to file. Then the master can recover the object. If someone knows a more elegant way or why assing does not work I appreciate comments.

sample code:

```
print(" paralelize with 8 cores ------------------------------")
library(doSNOW)
cl<-makeCluster(8)
registerDoSNOW(cl)
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(randomForest))
clusterExport(cl, "x")
clusterExport(cl, "y")
clusterExport(cl, "x.selected")

makeModel <- function(i){
  m <- randomForest(x,x.selected[i,],mtry=250,sampsize=3200,ntree = 3000,do.trace=TRUE) 
  eval(parse(text = paste("model_",i," <- m",sep="")))
  eval(parse( text =paste("save(model_", i, ", file =\"model_", i, ".Rdata\")",sep="" ) ))
}

foreach(i = 1:length(x.selected[,1]),.verbose = TRUE ) %dopar% makeModel(i)
stopCluster(cl)

foreach(i = 1:length(x.selected[,1]),.verbose = TRUE ) %do% 
load(paste("model_",i,".RData",sep=""))
```

Comment: I don't know which type of object `foreach` returns, it seems that it returns not a list of objects by default. Maybe it tries to combine somehow results of each node and fails to do that. But you can use `clusterApply` instead of `foreach`. Then you will receive a list of models as a result.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't specify a .combine function, foreach will return a list in order to handle arbitrary objects just like the clusterApply function.  Many foreach examples use `.combine="c"`, but that won't work with randomForest model objects.  If the body of the foreach loop evaluates to the randomForest model object, foreach will return a list of those objects.

Here is a simplified version of the randomForest example from the foreach package that returns model objects in a list and combines them afterwards.  I also modified it to use the doSNOW package as in your example:

```
library(doSNOW)
library(randomForest)
cl <- makeCluster(8)
registerDoSNOW(cl)
nr <- 1000
x <- matrix(runif(100000), nr)
y <- gl(2, nr/2)
rf <- foreach(ntree=rep(125, 8), .packages='randomForest') %dopar% {
  randomForest(x, y, ntree=ntree)
}
crf <- do.call('combine', rf)
print(crf)
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Can you guide me how can I modify this code to use on a university cluster, where I want to run this job on 4 different nodes, each node having 12 cores. I have a huge dataset and I want to make 1056 trees (22*48, 22= tree per core, 48 cores). I am using following code but it is not working, it has loaded just first node with all the burden hence it ran out of memory, and rest of the nodes are idle: `registerDoSNOW(makeCluster(48))` `rf <- foreach(ntree=rep(22,48), .combine=combine, .packages="randomForest") %dopar% randomForest(trainData[,-1], trainData$HCT116, ntree=ntree, norm.votes=FALSE)`

Comment: as per your recommendation I figured it out how can I make clusters on my university's high performance cluster. I'm using the following code but I think it is unable to parallelize efficiently, as the node having 64 cores and 2 TB RAM, goes out of memory. Kindly take a look if there is any problem n there. `library(doSNOW)
library(foreach)
library(randomForest)
trainData <- read.table("trainData.txt", sep="\t", header=T)
testData <- read.table("testData.txt", sep="\t", header=T)
nodelist <- readLines(Sys.getenv("OAR_NODEFILE"))`

Comment: `oar_job_id = as.numeric(Sys.getenv("OAR_JOB_ID"))
connector = paste0("OAR_JOB_ID=", oar_job_id)
connector = paste0(connector, " roarsh")

registerDoSNOW(makeCluster(nodelist, type="SOCK", rshcmd = connector))
rf <- foreach(ntree=rep(84,12), .combine=combine, .multicombine=T, .packages="randomForest")
%dopar% randomForest(trainData[,-1], trainData$Class, ntree=ntree,
norm.votes=FALSE)` dim of my trainData is: 46409553*9

Comment: @Newbie It's a bit awkward since I can't reproduce this, but if you're running out of memory then you probably need to start fewer workers per node. In your job submission, request more nodes, but fewer cores/cpus per node.

Comment: I think my problem is that my train data is very huge (47600811*9). I was thinking that if I bootstrap from my real train data (let's say 1000 sub samples of dim 10000*8) and iteratively generate trees for all of them and at the end combine all tress into 1 forest (as you've already answered in this question) then it will overcome my problem. What do you think about this?

Comment: Just to try this idea can you please guide me how can I generate random sample with replacement from my actual trainData and optimally generate trees for them iteratively? It will be great help. Thanks.

Comment: I have posted a new question on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39494010/random-forest-bootstrap-training-and-forest-generation) It will be great help if you can answer it there. Thanks.