# Random forest bootstrap training and forest generation

Tags: r, parallel-processing, random-forest, statistics-bootstrap, snow

I have a huge training data for random forest (dim: 47600811*9). I want to take multiple (let's say 1000) bootstrapped sample of dimension 10000*9 (taking 9000 negative class and 1000 positive class datapoints in each run) and iteratively generate trees for all of them and then combine all those trees into 1 forest.
A rough idea of required code is given below. Can anbody guide me how can I generate random sample with replacement from my actual trainData and optimally generate trees for them iteratively? It will be great help. Thanks

```
library(doSNOW)
library(randomForest)
cl <- makeCluster(8)
registerDoSNOW(cl)

for (i=1:1000){
B <- 1000 
U <- 9000 
dataB <- trainData[sample(which(trainData$class == "B"), B,replace=TRUE),] 
dataU <- trainData[sample(which(trainData$class == "U"), U,replace=TRUE),] 
subset <- rbind(dataB, dataU)
```

I am not sure if it is the optimal way of producing a subset again and again (1000 times) from actual trainData.

```
rf <- foreach(ntree=rep(125, 8), .packages='randomForest') %dopar% {
  randomForest(subset[,-1], subset$class, ntree=ntree)
}
}
crf <- do.call('combine', rf)
print(crf)
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the randomForest sampsize argument to a smaller value? Setting sampsize smaller and ntree higher may be similar to what you're doing.

Comment: @steve-weston I'm trying to create subset of actual data by `i = replicate(3, {c(sample(which(trainData$class == "B"), 50, replace = T), sample(which(trainData$class == "U"), 50, replace = T))})` and then apply foreach `rf <- foreach(ntree=rep(125, 8), .packages='randomForest') %dopar% {randomForest(trainData[i,-1], trainData[i,]$class, ntree=ntree, sampsize=rep(2,2))}` and later combine trees by `crf <- do.call('combine', rf)`. Then I get only 1000 trees while as my `i` contains 3 subsets and for every subset I am generating 1000 trees then I should get 3000 trees. How to correct it ?

Comment: Your program has a bug in it that I describe and fix in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your example parallelizes the inner rather than the outer loop, it may work reasonably well as long as the inner foreach loop takes more than a few seconds to execute, which it almost certainly does. However, your program does have a bug: it is throwing away the first 999 foreach results and only processing the last result. To fix this, you could preallocate a list of length 1000*8 and assign the results from foreach into it on each iteration of the outer for loop. For example:

```
library(doSNOW)
library(randomForest)
trainData <- data.frame(a=rnorm(20), b=rnorm(20),
                        class=c(rep("U", 10), rep("B", 10)))
n <- 1000         # outer loop count
chunksize <- 125  # value of ntree used in inner loop
nw <- 8           # number of cluster workers
cl <- makeCluster(nw)
registerDoSNOW(cl)
rf <- vector('list', n * nw)
for (i in 1:n) {
  B <- 1000
  U <- 9000
  dataB <- trainData[sample(which(trainData$class == "B"), B,replace=TRUE),]
  dataU <- trainData[sample(which(trainData$class == "U"), U,replace=TRUE),]
  subset <- rbind(dataB, dataU)
  ix <- seq((i-1) * nw + 1, i * nw)
  rf[ix] <- foreach(ntree=rep(chunksize, nw),
                    .packages='randomForest') %dopar% {
    randomForest(subset[,-1], subset$class, ntree=ntree)
  }
}
cat(sprintf("# models: %d; expected # models: %d\n", length(rf), n * nw))
cat(sprintf("expected total # trees: %d\n", n * nw * chunksize))
crf <- do.call('combine', rf)
print(crf)
```

This should fix the problem that you mention in the comment that you directed to me.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer. I am trying it on my real data, let's see if it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I generated a list of 100*100 and then made a loop for i = 1:100, then I am generating (125*8) trees in every foreach. I think I should be getting 125*8*100 =  100000 trees but actually I am getting 1250000. Can you guide me why is it happening..? Thanks.

Comment: @Newbie I made my example complete, so you can run it yourself. In the process, I fixed a few problems. I was computing the length of the result list incorrectly because I was mixing up the number of results and the total number of trees.

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work

```
# Replicate expression 1000 times, store output of each replication in a list
# Find indices of class B and sample 9000 times with replacement
# Do the same 1000 times for class U. Combine the two vectors of indices

i = replicate(1000, {c(sample(which(trainData$class == "B"), 9000, replace = T), sample(which(trainData$class == "U"), 1000, replace = T))})
```

Then feed `i` into a parallel version of lapply

```
mclapply(i, function(i, ntree) randomForest(trainData[i,-1], trainData[i,]$class, ntree=ntree)
```

Comment: Can you guide me how can I use this parallel version of lapply in above mentioned `foreach` command for computing trees for every `i`(subset from trainData), so that later on I can combine all trees into forest.  Actually what I need is to pass this `i` to this line of code in above example `randomForest(subset[,-1], subset$class, ntree=ntree)` the first argument will be all subset dataframe instead of first column which is `class` and the second argument will be the `class` column of that subset dataframe.

Comment: I think what you suggested here is to replace the line after the `%dopar%`, which is `{
  randomForest(subset[,-1], subset$class, ntree=ntree)
}` with `{mclapply(i, function(i, ntree) randomForest(trainData[i,-1], trainData[i,]$class, ntree=ntree)}`. Am I right?

Comment: I have tried it this way `rf <- foreach(ntree=rep(4,8), .packages="randomForest") %dopar% mclapply(i, function(i, ntree) randomForest(trainData[i,-1], trainData[i,]$class, ntree=ntree))` but it is giving the error: `task 1 failed - "could not find function "mclapply""` although a simple test of function mclapply works: `simplify2array(mclapply(rep(4, 5), rnorm, mc.preschedule = FALSE, mc.set.seed = FALSE))`

Comment: @Newbie No, you don't use `%dopar%` with` mclapply`. `dopar` is a parallel version of `for loop`, `mclapply` is a parallel version of `lapply`. In R, `*apply` is effectively the same as a `for loop` What happens when you run the code verbatim? I don't any data so I can't test the code.

Comment: If I run it like this: `rf <-  mclapply(i, function(i, ntree) randomForest(trainData[i,-1], trainData[i,]$HepG2, ntree=rep(4,8)))` Then I get this error: `Warning message:
In mclapply(i, function(i, ntree) randomForest(trainData[i, -1],  :
  all scheduled cores encountered errors in user code`. It would be better if you can suggest me how can I use this `mclapply` chunk in my original code given in the question.

Comment: Can you please take a look into this. Thanks